# Triggering Reactivity From List of Objects in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a list of objects:

```js
let message1 = {message: 'message one', is_visible: true};
let message2 = {message: 'message two', is_visible: true};

let message_list = [message1, message2]
```

I use the `is_visible` property to track whether or not the message should be visible. Here is the Svelte code:

```html
{#if message1.is_visible}
    <p>{message1.message}</p>
{/if}

{#if message2.is_visible}
    <p>{message2.message}</p>
{/if}
```

I want to hide all messages. How do I do this? Updating the `is_visible` property of each message by looping through the `message_list` does not work:

```js
message_list = message_list.map(({is_visible, ...rest}) => ({...rest, is_visible: false}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things

1. with the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=de) in the `.map()` function `message1` and `message2` stay the same and `message_list` contains new objects instead afterwards. This can be solved by changing to

```
message_list = message_list.map(message => {
            message.is_visible = false
            return message
        });
```

2. The UI still won't update because there's an assignment to `message_list`, but the `#if` blocks are based on `message1` and `message2`. By adding an [assignment to themselves](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive) they would update

```
        message_list = message_list.map(message => {
            message.is_visible = false
            return message
        }); 
        message1 = message1
        message2 = message2
```

Alternatively an update could be triggered by using a [`#key`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-key) block

```
{#key message_list}
    {#if message1.is_visible}
    <p>{message1.message}</p>
    {/if}

    {#if message2.is_visible}
    <p>{message2.message}</p>
    {/if}
{/key}
```

or by using the elements in the array inside the `#if` blocks

```
{#if message_list[0].is_visible}
    <p>{message_list[0].message}</p>
{/if}

{#if message_list[1].is_visible}
    <p>{message_list[1].message}</p>
{/if}
```

or by rendering the messages with an `#each` block based on `message_list`

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b17cffb8831e4f02b7df3d3b31f7b5bb?version=3.57.0)

```
<script>
    let message1 = {message: 'message one', is_visible: true};
    let message2 = {message: 'message two', is_visible: true};

    let message_list = [message1, message2]

    function hideMessages() {       
        message_list = message_list.map(message => {
            message.is_visible = false
            return message
        }); 
    }

</script>

{#each message_list as message}
    {#if message.is_visible}
    <p>{message.message}</p>
    {/if}
{/each}

<button on:click={hideMessages}>
    hide messages
</button>
```

(The last two would also work with the destructured `.map()` since only modifications to `message_list` matter.)

Comment: Incredibly thoughtful and insightful answer, thank you!